# User-friendly maintenance of the PostGIS geodatabase

Tags: postgis

We have a PostGIS geodatabase that is populated by several people. The base is gradually growing, and it becomes unclear to users what data we have and how to find it. In fact, only the person who loaded the data into the database knows about them. This can lead to data duplication.

The only thing that comes to mind is maintaining an Excel table describing the data.

Are there better ways to find and catalog information in a PostGIS geodatabase?

Comment: Have you searched on terms like "catalog service" and "geoportal"?

Comment: To some extent this is a *people* problem, not a data issue. You need to have policies for granting access to other users. Note that, if you have an Esri Enterprise geodatabase, the `sde.sde_layers` catalog and `sde.gdb_items` table would contain the information you want to store in Excel.

Comment: You can save anything that you can save into Excel also into database. You can make it automatic so that metadata and catalog tables are updated at the same time when your user loads data. However, you must first plan the process, then implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the information returned by this query:

```
select
    * --trim down the list to just what you want, there's lots in there
from
    information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public' --create 'IN' statement, etc. for other schemas
```

Now, a few things I would recommend:

- Build a view in your database based on the query above
- Consume the view in a LibreOffice spreadsheet
- Place the spreadsheet on a shared drive that others can access, which will update whenever new tables are added / removed, etc.
- Note you can add lots of info about the tables in the query above, which will show up in the spreadsheet

Also: consider deploying a dev/qa/prod system of data. If you have lots of people adding data, does that data go into their own use, or does it get promoted to tables that are used in a production system? That way you can limit the importing of data to the dev environment, and promote it to prod in a workflow that can be limited to a few users instead. If users need to import data for their own analysis, they can use the dev space as much as they want.